# Using get-effectiveaccess cmdlet from PowerShell Access Control Module the Domain Controller timesout

Tags: powershell

I get someone's primary AD Group memberships:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user2 | select distinguishedName
```

Then for each value in that list I use get-effectiveaccess
and what I have found is if I do that for someone with 32+ groups it starts to slow down and the domain controller becomes nonresponsive and sometimes returns errors.

Why?  I have add a delay of up to 5 seconds between get-effectiveacess invocations but that has no effect other than slowing it down. It seems to be tied to doing it 64 times or so from a single computer.  I also tried closing and re opening powershell between use of get-effectiveaccess